# Android Navigation Drawer Items linked to Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, navigation-drawer

In my application I created a Navigation Drawer which has 5 items, once an item is clicked in the Navigation Drawer, I can correctly check the item and show the new fragment using the fragment manager. 
But currently I have three problems:

1. My application has floating action buttons, that of course perform actions and open new fragments, so I need to handle that "Fragment changing" in the navigation drawer too, setting as checked the current item which corresponds to the fragment showed.

   - I **SORT OF** solved this problem, but using a single method that
     performs the fragment transaction in the MainActivity and meanwhile
     checks the new item. So everytime a Fragment want to call another
     Fragment, it uses this function passing the nav_drawer_item_id as a
     parameter. I think that this solutions sucks, so if you have a better idea, it would be really welcome!
2. My biggest problem is that when the user press the Android Back Button, the fragment pops back to previous one (or sometimes I call popback() programmatically because I am done with that specific fragment )

   - I really don't know how to solve this problem because I can't check the correct item in the navigation drawer once a fragment is popped back, I need to know which fragment it is.
3. I need to show the new fragment once the navigation drawer is closed in order to respect "Android Rules" ( And because it's nice ).

   - I sort of solved this problem too, by setting a "nextFragment" inside the navigation drawer onNavigationItemSelectedListener and by showing the new fragment inside the drawer onDrawerClosed. Is it the only solution?

I'm not posting any code because it really doesn't deserve to be seen, so here is some extra info:

- I have a single activity which contains the Navigation Drawer and currently handles the fragment transactions.
- I have 6 fragments, 5 called from the Navigation Drawer and 1 called only from others UI components, but this one doesn't need to be checked on the drawer of course.

  - I tought about a solution and it was like "Setting the checked item FROM the fragment that is showed", but I didn't find any way to get the Navigation Drawer from the Fragment in order to set the proper item checked.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener` in your activity to get notified whenever something is popped off the back stack and sync the navigation drawer from the callback. That should get rid of the problem caused when the back button is pressed.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    .....

    getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackStackChanged() {

    // Get the currently active fragment
    Fragment fragment = 
        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragments_frame);

    // Check which fragment is active, check the
    // correct selection and set the title accordingly
    if (fragment instanceof FragmentAtPosition0) {
        setCheckedAndTitle(0);
    } else if (fragment instanceof FragmentAtPosition1) {
        setCheckedAndTitle(1);
    }
}

private void setCheckedAndTitle(int position) {
    MenuItem item = navView.getMenu().getItem(position);
    item.setChecked(true);
    setTitle(item.getTitle());
}
```

As for the other two cases that you mentioned, I think the solutions you have mentioned are the preferred ways.